# Compound rigid body in cycles

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I would like to create a compound rigid body. I had a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGAwRKPlpCw), therein compound bodies were created by sampling primitive bodies together. The collision shape was set to a primitive like box or capsule. Than these bodies were all parented an so connected to each other and acted as a complex body.

However, the video used the blender-game mode, where the physics panel looked different to the one available in cycles-mode. In opposite to the video there is no option to set the collision bounds to compound.

But probably some images to explain:

That hook is the a hierarchy of 9 cylinders, each is a rigid body.

[image]

That is how it looks like in the outline:

[image]

This is the view of the physics panel:

[image]

Finally I connected each body with another, using »fixed« as constraint type, but all in all, the resulting body is not stiff and deforms, what is not what I want. I would like to have a completely stiff body. How can I gain that?

Comment: Could you provide your .blend as a starting point? What you are looking for should be possible.

Comment: You'll probably have to increase the number constraint solver iterations in *Scene > rigid body world*. That said, you might be better off using the *Triangle mesh* collision shape on a normal hook model. Also note that this feature was written as [part of the 2013 Gsoc](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sergof/GSoC2013/Documentation), but doesn't seem to be integrated yet..

Comment: You can also use **Override Iterations** and increase the number of iterations in the constraint panel for the constraints.

Comment: give it a shot…

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in official blender at the moment, however this feature was [written as part of the 2013 GSOC](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sergof/GSoC2013/Documentation).
<sub>I haven't seen word of it since, so if someone knows why it hasn't been integrated with master yet, please tell me :P</sub>

The closest you can get is the *Mesh* collision shape:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an option for you, but you could Join the meshes (Ctrl-J) into a single mesh, eliminating the need for Fixed constraints.

If that is not an option, then increasing the number of iterations as suggested by gandalf3 and user2859 is probably the best way to work around the wiggle inherent in the Bullet physics engine.